Postgres cross-database references are not implemented
I am connected to the postgres database, we have two databases, each of which includes several schemas - 'clients' database and 'products' database. When i try to write a simple select * limit 100 from the 'clients' database, get an error cross-database references are not implemented: "clients.raw_metrica.raw_orders".
In the meantime, I can specify only the schema and table names from the second database and everything works.
I've checked several similar questions here, but none of them fit my case. I don't have capital letters in the name of schemas and databases.
How can I fix this?
select * from clients.raw_metrica.raw_orders limit 100;


What version of Postgres are you using, and how have you set-up cross-database references? e.g. are you using postgres_fdw?


PostgreSQL 15.6
this is probably a stupid question, but where can i check it?


SELECT * FROM pg_extension; For details about postgres_fdw, just check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html
